# mysql sql query to avoid week-end day in a sum of date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to get out a sum of the days any employer worked, but in this sum mysql count week day, so the result is not exact.
How can avoid to get week days in the sum() function ?

I've tried with:

```
where mydate NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

as i saw in other answers for similar question , but here i use a group function, which means that the sum will be evaluated before where clause is called.

This is my query:

```
select  pp.person_name,sum(ss.spread_sheet_date) as days
  from    spread_sheet ss 
  left join activity ac on ss.activity_id = ac.activity_id
  left join person pp on pp.person_id = ss.person_id
  where ac.activity_id is not null
  group by ac.activity_id,pp.person_id ;
```

And this is my query with NOT IN:

```
select  pp.person_name,sum(ss.spread_sheet_date) as days
  from    spread_sheet ss 
  left join activity ac on ss.activity_id = ac.activity_id
  left join person pp on pp.person_id = ss.person_id
  where ac.activity_id is not null and  ss.spread_sheet_date  NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
  group by ac.activity_id,pp.person_id ;
```

I also find in another question this answer and i tried to use it

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ((DATEPART(dw, date_created) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

but it doesn't work, i suppose that is not mysql compatible.

Does Anyone know how to solve it ?

Comment: Please post a schema, sample data, current result and desired result - ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: It's a generic question - How to avoid to get sunday and saturday in a sum of date. Not need a schema

Comment: Have you try to using having clause?

Comment: The fact you haven't had any answers suggests a schema might be useful...both the things you've tried look like they should work. It's much easier to answer a specific question than a generic one.

Comment: @Krismorte How to use having in this case ?

Comment: Sorry @putz the ss.spread_sheet_date column is not in the select statemente so cannot be used. Show us the result of query with all columns. Another thing the text ss.spread_sheet_date is exactly like this 'Saturday' or is case sensity? try this  UPPER(ss.spread_sheet_date)  NOT IN ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm: in part of your query, you treat `ss.spread_sheet_date` as a number that can be summed (maybe you meant to count?), in other parts you treat it as a date. If it's really a date, then change:

```
where ac.activity_id is not null and  ss.spread_sheet_date  NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

to:

```
where ac.activity_id is not null and  DAYOFWEEK(ss.spread_sheet_date)  NOT IN (1,7)
```